# How to edit Flutter project in android studio - get file is read-only message

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I have a project in android studio that I made.
the project worked fine but now when I try to edit any files in the project folder I get
file is read-only [image]

any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: any other files are accessible live Constant or any other from welcome

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1. Close Android Studio.
2. Save .idea folder for future restore (if something happend)
3. Remove .idea folder
4. Start Android Studio and open project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried this but same result, after I delete the .idea folder its build again and the same message appeared.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly edit file inside **android** folder.
Follow these steps

1. Right click on android open
2. click on open in android studio
3. only android code base is open in different window of Android studio
4. then you can edit and then it will auto reflect code in your flutter project